# InvalidType error help me resolve?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

Hi this is my schedulable class here i'm calling my apex class
but it shows

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: Service at line 6 column 34

```
global class SchedulingService implements Schedulable {

   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

          Service s = new Service(); 
         // b.getIncident();method in my apex class
          //database.executebatch(b);
   }
}
```

please help me to resolve

Thanks

Comment: Suresh, can you please post first line of "Service" class?

Comment: thanks for replying.Service is my apex class how can i put   __c as extension Ashwani

Comment: You don't need __c for a class. Looks like you want to instantiate an object. Error on that line suggests its looking for a class which does not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define Service first. Then only you can use it in Scheduler.